# AttributeError: 'TemplateResponse' object has no attribute 'context_data'

Tags: python, django, caching

I get this error when I try to access a cached url.

I'm using per-view cached with Django, and when I access the url by the first time it works ok, but when it supposed to be in cache returns this error. I use FileBasedCache. This is in my settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 60,
        'OPTIONS': {
        'MAX_ENTRIES': 1000
        }
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES + (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware'
)
```

In urls.py something like this:

```
...
cache_page(60*1)(MyClaseView.as_view())
...
```

I've chacked directory permissions, everything's ok, there are .djcache files in there so it's writting

By the way, this error comes from a middleware (process_template_response) where I add some data to context_data.

Here is Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nexonet/.virtualenvs/esmidoctor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 136, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/home/nexonet/webapps/esmidoctor/esmidoctor/apps/common/middleware/template_article.py", line 12, in process_template_response
    response.context_data['template_admin'] = 'panel/content/base.html'
AttributeError: 'TemplateResponse' object has no attribute 'context_data'
```

Comment: You may need to show the traceback also.

Comment: Which version of django are you using?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.7.3

Comment: Show the `template_article.py` please.